# Matplotlib can't accept markevery be slice

Tags: python, matplotlib

It's really strange problem, I'm first time to use markevery term, `plot_list` is a list with 80 float number, and the main code are:

```
x=range(0,80)
plt.plot(x,plot_list, color= 'blue', ls='solid', marker='*',mfc = 'blue',ms=8,markevery=slice(50,70,2), label='LSTM')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

but it raises `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`, I'm really confused by this error, can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the definition of plot_list? I tried your code with plot_list=np.random.normal(size=[80]) on both python 2 and python 3 and it worked for me.

Comment: Slice is working fine, so you need to provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how to use a `slice` for the `markevery` argument to `plot`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(40)

x=range(0,80)
plot_list = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(len(x))-0.4)

plt.plot(x,plot_list, ls='solid', 
         marker='*',ms=8,markevery=slice(50,70,2), label='LSTM')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]